# erlang type notations T1:: A | B | C?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to code an type notation example but I can't get it to compile. What is the correct way to use type notation?

```
-module(type_notation).
-type person()  :: {person, name(), age()}.
-type people()  :: [person()].
-type name()    :: {firstname, string()}.
-type age()     :: integer().

[{person, {firstname, "john"}, 35}, {person, {firstname, "mary"}, 26}].
```

I get a warning for every type that says is unused.

I tried creating a type people that creates a type person, etc... I was expecting to get a type definition.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can't define modules like this:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).


[1, 2, 3].
```

In the shell:

```
4> c(a).             
a.erl:6:1: syntax error before: '['
%    6| [1, 2, 3].
%     | ^
```

Modules are for defining functions, which return stuff, so this compiles:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

go() ->
    [1, 2, 3].
```

Secondly, the following line does not use your type definition:

```
[{person, {firstname, "john"}, 35}, {person, {firstname, "mary"}, 26}].
```

To use your type definition, you have to write `people()` somewhere in your code.  Here's an example:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

-type person()  :: {person, name(), age()}.
-type people()  :: [person()].
-type name()    :: {firstname, string()}.
-type age()     :: integer().

-record(city, {
                id :: integer(),
                citizens = [] :: people()  %% USING TYPE HERE
              }).

go() ->
    #city{id=10, 
          citizens=[{person, {firstname, "Joe"}, 19}, 
                    {person, {firstname, "Kathy"}, 20}]
         }.
```

In the shell:

```
4> c(a).
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

5> NYC = a:go().
{city,10,
      [{person,{firstname,"Joe"},19},
       {person,{firstname,"Kathy",20}}]}

6> NYC#city.id.
* 1:4: record city undefined

7> rr(a).    NEEDED TO READ RECORD DEFINITION INTO THE SHELL
[city]

8> NYC.
#city{id = 10,
      citizens = [{person,{firstname,"Joe"},19},
                  {person,{firstname,"Kathy",20}}]}
COMPARE OUTPUT OF LINE 8 TO LINE 5

9> NYC#city.id.    NOW THIS WORKS
10

10> NYC#city.citizens.
[{person,{firstname,"Joe"},19},
 {person,{firstname,"Kathy",20}}]
```

You should be aware that the erlang compiler does not enforce types:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

-type person()  :: {person, name(), age()}.
-type people()  :: [person()].
-type name()    :: {firstname, string()}.
-type age()     :: integer().

-record(city, {
                id :: integer(),
                citizens = [] :: people()
              }).

go() ->
    #city{id=10, 
          citizens=[1, 2, 3]   %% CHANGED THIS
         }.


5> c(a).
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

6> rr(a).
[city]

7> NYC = a:go().     
#city{id = 10,citizens = [1,2,3]}

8> NYC#city.citizens.
[1,2,3]
```

The story goes that the erlang inventors discussed implementing type checking, but no one knew how to write a type checker, so they didn't.  People have tried after the fact but they haven't been able to.  You can do some type checking by running your program through [Dialyzer](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html).

If you don't use Dialyzer, then specifying types serves only to document your code, i.e. types are like helpful comments.